# Developing a Steam related site. failed to open stream: HTTP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm developing a CSGO Roulette gambling website using the Steam API, and for some reason i've been getting this dirty HTTP error for a majority of my time. It will not allow me to sign in because of a failed request. But then it also says it's "Forbidden."

Codes:

PHP Error Code:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=&steamids=76561198152444227): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 318

Line 318:

```
$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/? key=&steamids=$matches[1]";
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost
order allow,deny
deny from 46.101.200.204
allow from all
```

When I login here is the URL:

```
http://localhost/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198152444227&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198152444227&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin&openid.response_nonce=2016-05-08T19%3A52%3A09Zld%2BYsJr3uGfMkX5JkFh8Rr%2FHO1M%3D&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890&openid.signed=signed%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=BGpN5UvqbSXnnmzdL4PQFyeCmNY%3D
```

Been looking around a lot and I haven't found a solution yet. If anyone has a solution to this issue I'd be super-duper pleased!

Comment: Just open the URL (http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=&steamids=76561198152444227)  manually: `Access is denied. Retrying will not help. Please verify your
key=
parameter.` - your key variable is empty. Check the steam-api documentation what you are supposed to put there.